# Extracting polyline of border between differing polygons using R or GRASS?

Tags: r, grass-gis, adjacency

I have a shapefile with polygons with an associated variable that can take different values. I would like to extract the borders between polygons of differing value (red and blue) as a polyline (dark black line).

I would prefer solutions in R but will accept other open source solutions.

[image]

Comment: Suspect its two steps - first dissolve polygons of the same colour, then do an intersect. Can be done with the rGEOS package. No time for a full answer right now, sorry.

Comment: Agree with @Spacedman but either way without data in the form of an example shapefile it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GRASS it would be a simple two step process. After importing the polygon vector into an appropriate GRASS location, you would run:

```
v.dissolve <your polygon vector> output=<output polygon dissolved> column=<your variable>
```

then, to get just the boundaries:

```
v.extract <output polygon dissolved> output=<polygon boundaries> type=boundary
```

Comment: This is an old answer. However, I came to have difficulties in extracting boundaries too. Posted in the grass-dev list, as I thought it could be a potentially special case with my data. The answer and the NOTES in the manual of [v.extract](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.extract.html#notes) hint to features that have a category. Boundaries usually don't have a category. So, either adding category numbers or extracting all layers via `layer=-1` is the way to go.